# Deriving Poisson process with crowding out (pausing if event arrives)

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Let $A(t)$ denote how often a specific event happens during $[0, t]$., $A(0) = 0$. With iid constant arrival rates, we could write

$$ \mathbf P[A(t+\delta t) - A(t) = 1] = \lambda \delta t + o(\delta t)$$

Working on this formulation then gives rise to the Poisson distribution.

I'm wondering what happens if events take positive time. Say $A(t)$ denotes the number of customers searching through your store. However, once a customer is in your store, it takes him $\gamma$ time to leave your store (where $\gamma$ is another poisson rate). While he is in your store, he blocks any other customer from entering.

In other words, if $B(t) \in \{0, 1\}$ denotes whether a customer is blocking your store,

$$ \mathbf P[A(t+\delta t) - A(t) = 1] = \begin{cases}\lambda \delta t + o(\delta t) & B(t) = 0\\ 0 & B(t) = 1\end{cases}$$

$$ \mathbf P[B(t+\delta t) = 1 \mid B(t) = 1] = \gamma \delta t \\
 \mathbf P[B(t+\delta t) = 1 \mid B(t) = 0] = \lambda \delta t $$

However, I wouldn't know what to do with this. Is this correctly set up? Is there a smarter way to set up the system? And how would I approach solving the arrival rate of customers conditional on $B(t) = 0$?

Comment: You can get proper spacing by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Comment: If the customer take a constant service time $\gamma$, then the differential equations you put down is incorrect? Not sure about what you want, you may describe the inter-arrival time of the system follows a shifted exponential distribution (except the first customer). Or, in queuing theory notation, it should be a M/D/1/1 system.

Comment: @BGM Sorry that should be not constant $\gamma$, rather poisson rate $\gamma$.

Comment: @BGM I'm trying to compute the unconditional arrival time (excluding the first customer) ("What is the expected number of arrivals if we let this start with $B(0) = 0$?. If there's an alternative specification that gives even cleaner results, I'm happy for that too.

Comment: So you said "it takes him $\gamma$ time to leave your store (where $\gamma$ is another poisson rate)" What do you mean by this? Do you mean the time is an exponential time with mean $\frac {1} {\gamma}$?

Comment: @BGM that's exactly what I mean

Comment: So you just have a two-state continuous time Markov chain. (M/M/1/1 system, i.e. without any buffer for queue)

Comment: @BGM If you say so. Do you have some reference for me? This isn't something I'm educated in at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain